# ZXing multiple QR code scanning from single image iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, zxing

Is it possible to scan multiple qr codes from a single image ? If so how can I implement it ? I have a requirement to scan all qr codes from the single image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the svn trunk, there's support for multiple QR codes in `QRCodeMultiReader`. Not sure what you're using on the iPad but (the widget or the objc library) but it should be pretty easy to tie the `QRCodeMultiReader` in to those.

Comment: I am using widget , and QRCodeMultiReader is in java and other languages not in cpp or objective -c ! can you let me know how can I tie it to widget ?

Comment: QRCodeMultiReader.cpp went into svn in r1986/issue 1027.

Comment: So it should be in the 2.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

The Java version of zxing, which is the main version, contains support for reading multiple barcodes in one image. Look at MultipleBarcodeReader. You'd have to port it, but, it's not that hard.

Comment: tnx for correcting me. I was looking at QR scanner (obj-c) and didn't find an easy solution. Deleting my wrong answer in a minute. :) And yes, Sharon is talking about barcodes, so my assumption was completely wrong.